# My App Crashes Google Services Framework x_X

Tags: android, cursor

My app checks for missed calls every x amount of time. All works fine, but after a while it will crash the Google Services Framework (com.google.process.gapps) and show a Force Close dialog. So I plugged the phone in and watched the LogCat and found this error while it's checking the missed calls.

> E/IMemory(11481): cannot dup fd=1023, size=1048576, err=0 (Too many
>   open files)
>
> E/IMemory(11481): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x8b06f0),
>   size=1048576, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are
>   not yet supported across processes.)
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481): java.lang.RuntimeException: No memory in memObj
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481):  at
>   android.database.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481):  at
>   android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:518)
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481):  at
>   android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:27)
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481):  at
>   android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:493)
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481):  at
>   android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:496)
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481):  at
>   android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:103)
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481):  at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
>
> E/JavaBinder(11481):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

Here is how I'm checking missed calls

```
String[] projection = { CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.NEW };
                     String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE + " AND " + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1";

Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, null, null);

if(c != null) {
     c.moveToFirst();
     int mMissedCallCount = c.getCount();
...
}
```

So looking at LogCat it's the cursor thats causing the problem. Am I doing something wrong here? Also what does it mean by "Too many open files"? I haven't opened any files - that I'm aware of anyways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you never call `c.close()` on your Cursor. Try adding that after you process the cursor and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Yup! You're absolutely right! I forgot to call close.. I'm marking this as the answer for now! Hopefully I wont have to uncheck it! :)